# Getting 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')' trying to add a Modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

This is the code.  Everything is working until I add the Modal from Bootstrap. Once I add the Modal that is the error that I am getting.  All my react hooks are within the function so I am very confused.

If I block out the Modal code it works.  Bootstap is already installed into my app as well
Any thoughts on what is causing it? I think it may be a I am stumped

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Spinner from "../components/Spinner";
import { Modal } from "react-bootstrap";

const AllContacts = () => {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);


  const fetchData = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/mycontacts`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`,
        },
      });
      const result = await res.json();
      if (!result.error) {
        setContacts(result.contacts);
      } else {
        console.log(result);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    setLoading(false);
  };

  // Call the async function within the useEffect
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div >
        <h1>Your Contacts</h1>
        <hr className="my-4" />

        {loading ? <Spinner splash="Loading Contacts..." /> : (

          <table className="table table-hover">
            <thead>
              <tr className="table-dark">
                <th scope="col">First Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Phone</th>
                <th scope="col">Email</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {contacts.map((contact) => (

                <tr key={contact._id} onClick={() => setShowModal(true)}>
                  <th scope="row">{contact.first_name}</th>
                  <th scope="row">{contact.last_name}</th>
                  <td>{contact.phone}</td>
                  <td>{contact.email}</td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        )}
      </div>
      <Modal show={showModal} onHide={() => setShowModal(false)}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Modal title</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>

        <Modal.Body>
          <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
        </Modal.Body>

        <Modal.Footer>
          <button>Close</button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>

    </>
  );
};
export default AllContacts;
```

[Error on Localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFDHU.png)

No clue what to try

Comment: Which version of React and react-bootstrap are you using? Have you checked for compatibility issues?

Comment: That means you are not getting result.contacts.

Comment: you can set conditions like that
              { contacts != null &&

contacts.map((contact) => ( ....

Comment: Got it fixed! There were some issues due to having two node_modules